# getting the integer value of date in java

Tags: java, swing

i want to convert the value of my date into an integer value, i am using a `jDateChooser`.

Currently in my code below the value for `inputDate` is fixed or assingned but i want it to be based on the date a user picks using the `jDateChooser`.

```
public void OnDateClick(){
    int inputDate = 20121220 ;//variable name for my  jDateChooser is "OnDateClick" which i want assign to inputDate
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
    String date = df.format(Integer.valueOf(inputDate));
    String s = date.format(date);
    int output = Integer.valueOf(s);
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

I will appreciate the help thank you.

Comment: Get the date from your `jDateChooser` and use your format on it?

Comment: Why is `inputDate` not a `String`?

Comment: You should never store/conform a date as a int. As some date representations could have leading zeros, and an integer cannot represent these. The best primitive datatypes for Date are Long (date.getTime()) or String, which is the human-readable format.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an object of jDateChooser available which is having the the user selected date?

Then :

```
// Set the date format 
jDateChooser.setDateFormatString("yyyyMMdd");

//to get the date
String inputDate = "";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
inputDate = sdf.format(jDateChooser.getDate());
```

Comment: should i add a listener to it? cos this code is giving me an exception error. i have the jDateChooser on my form . Am curious tho what does the input variable do? am new at java so plsss pardon me.

Comment: Yes, you will have to have a listener in the page where you have the jDateChooser, and when the user clicks the apply button(or someother button),listener should be invoked and in the onEvent method of your page, you should read the value from the jDateChooser and parse it to your string

Answer (score 0):

If you have an `int` of the form `yyyyMMdd` like your example `20121220` and want a `String` of the form `yyyyMMdd` then the form doesn’t really matter as the value has the desired form already.

Just use `String date=Integer.valueOfString.valueOf(inputDate);` Don’t use `df.format(Integer.valueOf(inputDate));`; this will interpret the number as milliseconds since a fixed date.

The conversion in the opposite direction is the same; *if* the string already has the form `yyyyMMdd` you can simply use `Integer.parseInt(date)`. So your entire example program yields to:

```
int inputDate = 20121220;
String date = String.valueOf(inputDate);

int output = Integer.parseInt(date);
System.out.println(output);
```

which might look a bit nonsense, but since you actually don’t really do anything with `Date`s in your example program the `DateFormat` becomes obsolete. More useful would be:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
int inputDate = 20121220;
Date date=df.parse(String.valueOf(inputDate));

int output = Integer.parseInt(df.format(date));
System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: what i need help with is that instead of the value "20121220" be assigned to inputDate, i want it being picked by my jdatechooser in an app am writing. So the date will be converted into an integer value and i will use that in a calculation. i hope my problem is clear now? So when i pick a date from my jdatechooser, it is converted into an integer and that integer or result will be used for further operations.

Comment: So I was right assuming that you wanted a `Date` rather than a `String` as the datepicker works in terms of `Date`s. So why don’t you use my last example which shows how to convert an integer to a `Date` and back to an integer? The empty line is the place where the datepicker might come in.

Comment: the empty line date? and if so what happens to the inputDate variable which has 20121220?

Comment: Sorry but I don’t understand your questions. There are three lines creating a `DateFormat` and convert your `int inputDate` variable to a `Date` which you can use, e.g. to initializer a date picker, that’s where the empty line is. After that there are two lines of code converting a `Date`, which could originate from the date picker, back to `int output` and print it out. Hey, there are only *five lines* of code and only two of them are actually doing conversions. There’s more text explaining the code than actual code. There’s even more explaining text in the comments than code in the answer.